# How to fix the error (attribute error) in tabula convert code in python?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, tabula

I'm trying to convert a pdf file to excel and I'm struggling. I did the pip install tabula as well. I also did the pip install tabula-py and still have the same problem.

This is the code I've done.

```
import tabula 
pdf_file = "Graycor_Q4_2022.pdf"
tabula.convert_into("Graycor_Q4_2022.pdf","output.csv", output_format = "csv", pages ='all')
```

I'm getting this error. Please help.

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>() ----> 1 tabula.convert_into("Graycor_Q4_2022.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')

AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'convert_into'
```